# How to increment/decrement speed on input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to increment and decrement the speed on object movement with input. What would the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no code i ll try my best to explain, whenever you are pressing down a key you can increase a variable and whenever you press another key you can decrease the variable. This should be done in the Update() method and it can go something like this

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
    {
        variable++;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("b"))
    {
        variable--;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I made a public float variable named Speed, I declare the speed variable in a void Awake method and set it to an amount and that the object should move towards the player. All good. With each input, I can see that the variable increases in the editor but the object doesn't actually increase its speed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well thats up to your code, like you have to link your speed variable to the actual movement in the axis you want to move

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go really depends on the features that you want to implement in your game and how you want the object movement to feel.

This is one way to do exactly what you asked though

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    private Vector2 velocity;
    public float playerMoveSpeed = 6; //the value that you want

    private float HorizontalMov;
    private float VerticalMov;

    void Awake() {
        rigidbody2D = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        HorizontalMov = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        VerticalMov = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        AddVelocity(new Vector2(HorizontalMov, VerticalMov));
        rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public void AddVelocity(Vector2 newVelocity) {
        velocity += newVelocity;
    }

}
```

You can learn more about [Input.GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) and [RigidBody2D.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) in the unity documentation

Comment: thanks! The objective is to use a weapon, with raycast, to increase/decrease speed on objects in a 3D environment. I.e using left mouse click, I want to decrease the speed on the initial speed of an object and the opposite using the right mouse click.

Comment: How you can increase/decrease the speed of these objects depends on how they are being moved (could you specify it?). You will need to access the object using the raycast and modify the parameter that is controlling its speed.

You also need to know the direction the object is moving.

Comment: hmm yes, I am thinking using an inital speed and transform position towards the player on said object. I want to raycast to the object and determine to either increase (left mouse button) or decrease (right mouse button) the speed of that object. Public variables of the direction  of the object is also something I would like to add, just a novice at coding : /

Comment: Ok, I think it would be better if you created a new question with details about everything you need and more info about your game. Like if it's a 3d or 2d game. Specifying that you want to move by modifying the transform position.